# Angular 1.5 - Auto fetch api updated values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was  wondering if this is possible without using a websocket. what I want to do is that every time the api data gets changed then It would automatically call on the service I made to refetch those values. I tried using a `setInterval function` but this seems like overkill and maybe prone to errors in the long run

Here is the code for my service:

```js
app.factory('ApiService',function($http,Config,$q){
 
 return {
  login: function(payload){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http({
    method:'POST',
    url:Config.baseUrl + '/api/login',
    data:payload,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
   }).then(function (result){             
    return deferred.resolve(result);
   }, function (result){
    return deferred.reject(result);
   });
   return deferred.promise;
  },
  dailyTransactions: function(apiToken){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http({
    method:'GET',
    url:Config.baseUrl + '/api/client/transaction/total/?token='+apiToken,
    headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Authorization':'token '+apiToken
    },
   }).then(function (result){             
    return deferred.resolve(result);
   }, function (result){
    return deferred.reject(result);
   });
   return deferred.promise;
  },
});
```

and my Controller code:

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($state,$scope,$position,$rootScope,$timeout,ApiService,toastr) {
  console.log($state);
  
  $rootScope.user = localStorage.getItem('username');
  var payload = localStorage.getItem('api_Key');

  $scope.showDailyTransactions = function(){
    ApiService.dailyTransactions(payload).then(function(response){
      $scope.apiData ={
        "total_sent":response.data.total_sent,
        "total_success":response.data.total_success,
        "total_pending_failed":response.data.total_pending_failed
      };

      $scope.daily = $scope.apiData; 
      
    }, function(error) {
     console.log(error);
   });

  }

  $timeout($scope.showDailyTransactions,5000);
  
});
```

Comment: And how would you know that data has changed? No way without either polling or websocket, or server side events.

Comment: The api is a service we are using, Good point ill look into the alternatives you suggested. For now the only way I'm able to monitor if it has changed is when I user the service.

Answer (score 0):

The only two choices really are websockets or polling. The former is newer and cooler, but more complicated to implement. The latter is much easier, but doesn't provide immediate updates (except long-polling which is a slightly more complicated implementation). If you need true real-time linkage between server and client data, then websockets is the way to go. I'd argue that regular $interval polling is adequate for most applications, though.

I'd suggest building a service that holds the data and does the polling to keep it updated, rather than doing it in your main controller.

Comment: Cool I'll try that thinking outside of the box here as I'm not really sure is there any way from the server side to do the polling lets say you're already authorized to access the api and you need some of those to execute on a given duration.